# How to check whether the inputted telephone no starting from 0 in twilio ?

Tags: php, twilio

when user input phone no as 09XXXXXXXX twilo only get 9XXXXXXXX. I want to check whether the user inputted digit count is 10.

Comment: As 9kv's answer says, you will need to store phone numbers as strings.  For checking digit counts, regular expressions are your friend. `/\d{10}/` will match a string that is ten digits long.  You can write much fancier regular expressions to allow, for example, free-form phone numbers, to check the leading digit for non-zero, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing the data as an integer, store it as varchar (I'm assuming you're using a MySQL database).

Reason being is that 001 == 1. However, "001" != "1".

Comment: yeah i have used this method.Thank you 9kv

Answer (score 0):

This example may help you.you can add your own other logics

```
    <?php
        $t = $_POST['t'];

        if(strlen($t)==11 && $t[0] == '0')//checked the string length and first character if 0
        {
            $finalt = substr($t,1); //exclude 0 from the number
            echo $finalt;
        }
        elseif(strlen($t)==10){
            echo($t);
        }
        else{
            echo('not a valid phone number');
        }   
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="number" name="t" id="t"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```